# "Дусити" - літературне слово чи росіянізм?

Tags: росіянізм, дієслова

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE) читаю:

> Назва села походить від слова «душити», «**дусити**», яке виникло у зв'язку з тим, що з усіх боків село стискали гори, немов душили його.

Зацікавило, чи слово "дусити", випадково, не росіянізм.

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/dusyty) слова "***дусити***" немає.

Однак у [Словнику чужомовних слів Павла Штепи, літери Ґ-Д](https://storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1312) є:

> душити (горлянку) – **дусити**, задусити, здусити, подусити, удусити.

Отже, ***дусити - українське літературне чи росіянізм***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Словнику лемківської говірки](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/3233/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) знаходимо, що це діалектизм:

> **дусити**
>   душу, дусиш, Ол.
>   Душити.

Також знаходимо це слово в [Словнику малозрозумілих слів](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1034818/233/Koli_zviri_rozmovlyali_Ukrainski_narodni_kazki_pro_tvarin.html):

> **дусити** — душити.

В [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) ( Т. 2., с.150) знаходимо:

> **душити** "давити, пригнічувати", душитися "задихатися", **[дусити]** "давити" Ж.

Отже, вся ця інформація є підтвердженням того, що **дусити** – це діалектизм, але не росіянізмом.